# Audio Recording using Arduino BT module

Tags: audio, hc-05, baud-rate

I want to take audio signal through mic connected to Arduino and then transfer it to PC using BT module. I want to do it with BT (HC05) and Arduino Mega. I need audio packages at 44 KHz and 24-32 bits per sample.

Can I use AudioInI2S library to receive audio samples? Does HC05 support this type of communication?

I want to save and analyze the audio samples later on. I have worked on Arduino before but I am totally new to audio streaming and I am not sure where to begin from. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: No and no.

---

> Can I use AudioInI2S library to receive audio samples?

No.  The library is not for the Mega:

> This library provides simple way to play and analyze audio data using Arduino on SAMD21 based boards (i.e Arduino or Genuino Zero, MKRZero or MKR1000 Board) using the I2S bus.

---

> Does HC05 support this type of communication?

No.  The HC05 is a serial module. It works at baud rates that are far to low to transfer the data in a timely fashion, and can't send data in a form the PC sees as audio (so you'd need to write your own translation software to convert serial data into an audio file).

---

> Any guidance would be appreciated.

Just buy a cheap bluetooth headset.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you suggest any other Bluetooth module that can support my frequency range?

Comment: Bluetooth headset is not an option as it is a part of some project that I am working on.