# Make a Jack-Bluetooth Module for the car

Tags: bluetooth, baud-rate

I'm making a Jack-Bluetooth module so that I can send music to the car (or other devices w/ Jack plug) without an internal Bluetooth module in the car.

https://habr.com/en/post/456182/ says that I need around 44 kHz of sampling frequency to get high quality sound. Is there a BT module on the market w/ these specs?

[Audio Recording using Arduino BT module](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/69034/audio-recording-using-arduino-bt-module) says that the HC-05 HC-06 HC-07 are not good enough.

If there are no such cases, I think I should consider buying an Arduino that has an built-in BT/WiFi module or I can buy such a BT transmitter but beats the fun.

Comment: Just buy a small bluetooth audio receiver. There's fun, there's torture, and then there's trying to make your own bluetooth audio receiver. It's just not worth the effort, even if you enjoy torture.

Comment: There is no way you will do it with a bluetooth "module" to an Arduino. You *need*: * A arduino with builtin bluetooth. * An Arduino with an I2S interface and high quality CODEC. * A lot of skill in programming and an in-depth knowledge of Bluetooth audio protocols.